# PHP session open(/tmp/sess_) Permission denied

Tags: php, session

I get this error which occurs when I go from http links to https or vice versa.
For example my test site http://dev.24houranswers.com/ seems fine. When you navigate to login
https://dev.24houranswers.com/login.php.. I get the error 
"open(/tmp/sess_6205f1dae5098a7b29ef63f2fa4a0a34, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied"

..Any suggestions?

Comment: Need to set the group permissions.  chown it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: "Permission denied"

You have no permission to write to that location. 
Either:

- Fix the permission on /tmp so the webserver process can write there
- Choose a different location where the webserver process can write, use `session_save_path ( 'mypath' )`
- Install a [custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) and write sessions to a file, database, memcache etc.